# cocoa code- how to reallocate the buffer in the method which i have used below?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

How to reallocate the buffer `buf`, in the method which I have used below?

```
[fileData getBytes: buf length: 1024];
```

In my code i have declared the buf as char n storing 1050 characters in that as `char buf[1050]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "reallocate" a buffer on the stack, the size of which is defined at compile time.  You will want to use dynamic allocation instead:

```
#define MYBUFLEN 1024
char *buf = (char *)malloc(MYBUFLEN);
[fileData getBytes:buf length:MYBUFLEN];
```

and don't forget to `free()` it when you're done with it, else you will leak memory pretty quickly:

```
free(buf);
```

Comment: Where exactly should i call this free(buf); function in my code? And as you have mentioned above we are defining the MYBUFLEN to 1024. But what if i want to open a file which is less than 1024 bytes, for ex. 154 bytes?